# How to filter double many to many relationships in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an `Organization` table and two relationships in it `Bikes`, and `Skateboards` (table names Bike and Skateboard).

User selects skateboard and bike and wants to see all organizations which have both.How could I achieve this?

I can join one many to many relationship, for example:

```
test = Organization.query.\
    join(Organization.bikes).\
    filter_by(bike_name="some bike name").all()
```

It returns those organizations, which contain `"some bike name"` in related table.

I tried also this, but it did not work:

```
test = Organization.query.\
    join(Organization.bikes).\
    join(Organization.skateboards).\
    filter_by(bike_name="some bike name").\
    filter_by(skate_name="some skate name").all()
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
  q = (Organization.query
    .filter(Organization
    .bikes.any(Bike.bike_name == 'some name'))
    .filter(Organization.skateboards.any(Skateboard.skateboard_name == 'some name'))
    .all())
```